# Erro ao tentar rodar o projeto no Meteor

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, framework, meteorjs

Sendo breve, não estou conseguindo rodar meu app no Meteor.

Eu crio o projeto normalmente ***meteor create nameProjet*** mas na hora de rodar (***comando "meteor"***) ele não apresenta

> http://localhost:3000

Que no caso informaria que a aplicação está rodando normalmente

Como era de se esperar

Apresenta o seguinte erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ele não está conseguindo rodar o Mongo, você tem ele instalado na sua máquina?

Comment: Acabei de instalar, é preciso alguma configuração para interação MongoDB + Meteor?

Comment: Olha esse post, deve te ajudar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971208/meteor-on-windows-10?utm_content=buffer23149&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Comment: Mike, Pergunta idiota: Já tentou rodar o comando? meteor npm install?

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se de que o Meteor está sendo executado no localhost. Abra o terminal e execute o comando de `meteor`. Ele vai começar a executar em localhost: 3000, se você não tiver alterado a porta.

Enquanto ele estiver em execução, abra um novo terminal e execute o comando `meteor mongo`. Isto irá abrir um shell MongoDB e irá lhe dizer qual porta ele está se conectando, normalmente será a 3001 a partir da versão 0.7.1.1, ou 3002, se anterior. Ele vai dizer algo como 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso, mas no segundo comando ele me retorna uma mensagem falando que `meteor mongo` é usado apenas quando o app está rodando localmente e manda eu fazer como voce já falou. [http://i.stack.imgur.com/QyQ7a.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QyQ7a.png) Voce não conhece nenhum tutorial que ensine como fazer essa configuração? Porque não estou conseguindo iniciar meus estudos sobre o Meteor devido a esse problema.

Comment: http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/meteor-run-without-creating-local-mongo-database, dá uma olhada se ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Eu não uso Meteor no Windows, mas a imagem diz que o erro é em virtude de ele não conseguir rodar o comando "tasklist.exe", por isso não consegue determinar o PID do Mongo, e não necessariamente que o Mongo não está rodando. Inclusive mostra onde ele chamou o comando (C:...\future:389:15.js).

Tentou rodar ele manualmente pra ver se ele se comporta da maneira esperada?

Provavelmente nesse arquivo ele mostre os parâmetros com o qual ele chame esse executável. É por onde eu começaria a investigar.

https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb491010.aspx